# Should I call from server or client if data is already on client side?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I feel this is a stupid question, but I am having a problem answering it myself, so I am relying on experienced programmers to help me with this.

I have a react app that is running on a laravel backend (php), and using redux for a presisted state for my app.

I essentially request all data that will be present on another page, and would like to know, if I should just use the data that I initially have in my redux store or just reload everything on a different page?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the data in `redux` store. But persisted data can be altered, so in case you want to verify the data or something along the lines, you can just compare the data that is on the client side with that on the server. Otherwise, the very idea of `redux` is to use data in multiple pages (`components`)